# Angular js Complex Json Objects

Tags: json, rest, angularjs, nested

I'm newbie to Angular Js.I would like to Create Complex Json Object for my Xml settings Like
**string Jsonobject=" {'Email': { 'UserName': 'a','Password': 'a'}}"**;
So far I tried

```
$scope.save = function () {

                var AddSettings = $resource('../AddSettings/');--Calling my WCF REST SERVICE

                var adminSettings = new AddSettings();

                adminSettings.Title = $scope.inputtitle;
                adminSettings.HomeUrl = $scope.intputhomeurl;

                //var arr = [];
                //arr.push(addmodule.Title);
                //arr.push(addmodule.HomeUrl);
                //addmodule.LogoSettings = arr;



                adminSettings.$save();
```

It's generating following Json Object : **{ "UserName": "a","Password": "a"}**,Can any one please guide me to create a json Object like **" {'Email': { 'UserName': 'a','Password': 'a'}}"** using Angular js.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in the following way.

```
var adminSettings = new AddSettings();
adminSettings.LogoSettings = {
                    Title: $scope.inputtitle,
                    HomeUrl: $scope.intputhomeurl,
                    logo: $("#ImageUpload > img").attr('src')
                };
adminSettings.$save();
```

It's returning Json object as  {'Email': { 'UserName': 'a','Password': 'a'}}.